# Try displaying three cards in a loop within a slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a slider component where I want to achieve a sequence in Inner Slider like [img1, img2, img3], then [img2, img3, img1], followed by [img3, img1, img2]. However, instead of this sequence, it currently behaves like [img1, img2, img3], then [img2, img3], and finally just [img3]. When the current state is back to 0, it starts again with [img1, img2, img3]. How can I achieve the desired sequence? I hope you understand.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
const image = [
   { banner: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/sRLC052ieEzkQs9dEtPMfFxYkej.jpg",
     poster: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/ui4DrH1cKk2vkHshcUcGt2lKxCm.jpg"
    },
    { banner: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/4HodYYKEIsGOdinkGi2Ucz6X9i0.jpg",
    poster: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/ui4DrH1cKk2vkHshcUcGt2lKxCm.jpg"
   },
   { banner: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/1jITxVJhkiFJuQuj8NcPLmDNtJg.jpg",
    poster: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/qjhahNLSZ705B5JP92YMEYPocPz.jpg"
   }
];

export default function Carousel() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  

  const nextImage = function () {
    setCurrent((current + 1) % image.length);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      nextImage();
    }, 2000);
  });

  const variants = {
    initial: {
      x: 1000,
      opacity: 0,
    },
    animate: {
      x: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 300, damping: 30 },
        opacity: { duration: 0.2 },
      },
    },
    exit: {
      x: -1000,
      opacity: 0,
      transition: {
        x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 300, damping: 30 },
        opacity: { duration: 0.2 },
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-[550px] overflow-hidden relative">
      <AnimatePresence initial={false} >
        <motion.img
          variants={variants}
          animate="animate"
          initial="initial"
          exit="exit"
          alt="slides"
          key={image[current]?.banner}
          className="slides z-20"
          src={image[current]?.banner}
        />

<div className="absolute w-[40%] h-auto overflow-hidden justify-center  top-1/2 translate-y-[-50%] gap-4 m-auto flex right-8 z-40" >
          {
            {/* Inner Slider */}
            image?.map((items,index)=>{
                return <motion.img src={items?.poster} key={index} className="w-[30%] object-cover" alt="" animate={{ x: `calc(-${current * 100}% - ${current}rem)` }}
                />
            })
          }
      </div>
        
      </AnimatePresence>
       
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a set of image clones to the right of the "real" images that move in as the "real" images move to the left. This makes it look like a loop. At the end of the loop, the positions reset seamlessly.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;
const { motion, AnimatePresence } = Motion;
const image = [
  {
    banner:
      'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/sRLC052ieEzkQs9dEtPMfFxYkej.jpg',
    poster:
      'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/ui4DrH1cKk2vkHshcUcGt2lKxCm.jpg',
  },
  {
    banner:
      'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/4HodYYKEIsGOdinkGi2Ucz6X9i0.jpg',
    poster:
      'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/ui4DrH1cKk2vkHshcUcGt2lKxCm.jpg',
  },
  {
    banner:
      'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/1jITxVJhkiFJuQuj8NcPLmDNtJg.jpg',
    poster:
      'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/qjhahNLSZ705B5JP92YMEYPocPz.jpg',
  },
];

function Carousel() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const nextImage = function () {
    setCurrent((current + 1) % image.length);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      nextImage();
    }, 2000);
  });

  const variants = {
    initial: {
      x: 1000,
      opacity: 0,
    },
    animate: {
      x: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        x: { type: 'spring', stiffness: 300, damping: 30 },
        opacity: { duration: 0.2 },
      },
    },
    exit: {
      x: -1000,
      opacity: 0,
      transition: {
        x: { type: 'spring', stiffness: 300, damping: 30 },
        opacity: { duration: 0.2 },
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-[550px] overflow-hidden relative">
      <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
        <motion.img
          variants={variants}
          animate="animate"
          initial="initial"
          exit="exit"
          alt="slides"
          key={(image[current] || {}).banner}
          className="slides z-20"
          src={(image[current] || {}).banner}
        />

        <div className="absolute w-[40%] h-auto overflow-hidden top-1/2 translate-y-[-50%] flex gap-4 m-auto right-8 z-40">
          {(image || []).map((items, index) => {
            return (
              <motion.img
                src={(items || {}).poster}
                key={index}
                className="w-[30%] object-cover"
                alt=""
                animate={{ x:
                  current === 0
                    ? [null, `calc(-300% - 3rem)`, `calc(0% - 0rem)`]
                    : `calc(-${current * 100}% - ${current}rem)`
                }}
                transition={{ times: [0, 1, 1] }}
              />
            );
          })}
          {(image || []).map((items, index) => {
            return (
              <motion.img
                src={(items || {}).poster}
                key={index}
                className="w-[30%] object-cover"
                alt=""
                animate={{ x:
                  current === 0
                    ? [null, `calc(-300% - 3rem)`, `calc(0% - 0rem)`]
                    : `calc(-${current * 100}% - ${current}rem)`
                }}
                transition={{ times: [0, 1, 1] }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<Carousel />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/framer-motion@10.17.0/dist/framer-motion.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```